# Can someone explain?

Tags: algorithms

How many times is the print statement executed, wehre i,j,k ∈ **Z**? Explain

> For *i* := 1 to 12 do
>
> For *j* :=5 to 10 do
>
> For *k*:=15 downto 8 do
>
> Print *(i-j)*k*

Comment: OMG! When you don't know what to do, try multiplying...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start inside and work out. The innermost loop executes once for each value of $k$ from $15$ down to $8$; that’s $15-7=8$ values, so the print statement is executed $8$ times every time the innermost loop is entered.

Now how often is the innermost loop entered? Once for each value of $j$ from $5$ to $10$, i.e., $10-4=6$ times. That is, every time the middle loop is entered, the innermost loop runs $6$ times, so the print statement is executed $6\cdot8=48$ times.

Can you finish it from there? How often is the middle loop entered?

Comment: @Peter: You’re welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Is the `print` command executed when $k=8$? Or is it possible to stop the process when $k=8$? Will this depend on the program language?

Comment: @Sigur: I’m assuming that `downto` works like `to`, which in every language that I’ve used includes the limit.